# Migration error when adding Linkedin Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use Linkedin's api for authentication in my rails app. I'm pretty new to rails so I followed this guide http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/

I've tried to run rake db:migrate but get this error. The full trace is below. I've also added the environment.rb file as I think that's where the problem is but I'm not sure. Also, if anyone has a better guide for using linkedin apis with rails please share! Thanks for the help!

rake aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
/Users/alexanderkehaya/Desktop/codea/codea_app/config/environment.rb:4:in`'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in`block in require'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in`require'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/application.rb:379:in`block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in`block in execute'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in`execute'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in`mon_synchronize'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in`block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in`invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in`mon_synchronize'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in`invoke'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in`block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in`block in top_level'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in`top_level'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in`standard_exception_handling'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in`'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/alexanderkehaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/rake:23:in`'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment

environemnt.rb file

```
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

config.app_domain = 'somedoamin.com'

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: config.app_domain }
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'smtp.gmail.com', 
  port: '587',
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: 'someuser',
  password: 'somepass',
  authentication: :plain,
  domain: 'somedomain.com'
 }

Rails.application.initialize!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `environment.rb` indeed is the problem. All of the config code in it:

```
config.app_domain = 'somedoamin.com'

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: config.app_domain }
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'smtp.gmail.com', 
  port: '587',
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: 'someuser',
  password: 'somepass',
  authentication: :plain,
  domain: 'somedomain.com'
 }
```

Is in the wrong place. It should be in the `application.rb` or `config/environments/development.rb` if its development specific.

Comment: o, I think that worked but I'm now getting this error. sorry not sure how t format in the comment.. Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_session' here is my routes file 'Rails.application.routes.draw do
  
  devise_for :users
  root 'pages#home'
  get "about" => "pages#about" #creates about path
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks' }
  match '/users/:id/finish_signup' => 'users#finish_signup', via: [:get, :patch], :as => :finish_signup'

Comment: Yea, you should start a new question.